# How fix building workspace error in Zend Studio?

Tags: zend-studio

How to fix building workspace problem in Zend Studio?

I'm trying to rename project and rename folder of project, however nothing:

> Errors occurred during the build.
> Errors running builder 'JavaScript
> Validator' on project 'PROJECT'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> [image]

Comment: You will have much better chances getting a solution to this issue at the [official Zend Forums](http://forums.zend.com/viewforum.php?f=48)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed, you can either wait for the new release or apply the patch :

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318004

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to the new version

Comment: How do I apply a patch?  I asked the same question over at Zend forums but never got an answer.  Just asked the same Q on Stackoverflow so as not to sidetrack this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000398/how-do-i-add-a-patch-to-an-eclipse-ide)

Comment: Here we are December, 2011. This bug wasn't fixed.

Answer (score 5):

you must go to Project->Properties->Builders then disable ‘Javascript Validator’.

Comment: Have you even considered that we actually want the javascript validator?

Comment: I'm annoyed. In the end, that was the only solution. And they charge you for this software built upon a open source project. Crap!

Comment: also new zend studio version have this problem. poor product

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and mine is that the saving workspace process try to write in one of the file and it can't even it is available under .metadata directory.

This is how I did:

Open the .metadata directory and look for that particular file, yours can be different, so
change it to read and write for this file then restart eclipse.

It fixed the problem!.

My OS: Ubuntu 10.04 , Eclipse SDK 3.5.2

Hope this help...

Comment: I have the latest version of Zend Studio 8.01 and I am still getting this, apparently fixed, bug. After reading your solution I did not fully understand what you meant, but I did go and make sure that the files in the .metadata directory were writable and it has fixed my problem. +1 for the help. Cheers.