# How do I add a patch to an eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse, patch, zend-studio

About once every couple months I find out that some irritating thing that Zend Studio does "will be fixed in the next version - or you can add the patch now".  Adding a patch isn't exactly intuitive though - I've deadended a couple times.

Could someone lay out the steps for me?  For example, applying the patch mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582304/how-fix-building-workspace-broblem-in-zend-studio).

(I asked this question a while ago [on the zend forums](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=23608#p68853), but it was never answered.)

Answer (score 1):

To apply such a patch, you have to

1. Download the source code of the corresponding Zend Studio/Eclipse plug-in into an Eclipse workspace that has the Plug-in development environment.
2. Then you can right click on the project, and select Team/Apply patch from the context menu.
3. And finally build and export the resulting plug-in, and install it into your environment.

Yes, it is not that simple, because in this case you have to recompile a part of the environment you are working with.